# Making a list of subscribers available across calls to a service

Tags: c#, wcf

So I have created a service that has a callback. Something like [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-events-and-callbacks). It works well enough but what I would like to do is have any client that has subscribed be notified that the service was called (and pass some data to the callback function) however this isn't as easy as I thought.

I created two clients, one to call the service and one to listen but although I can see the "listener" (client one) subscribe, on the subsequent call to the service (from client two) the list of subscribers is empty (well except for the calling service, which also subscribes). The first client I started isn't in the list of subscribers. I tried a few tricks to solve this and all of them have failed. Essentially what I tried was a hack to create a static class that kept a static list of subscribers.

a couple of noteworthy requirements. This has to be an http binding so I am using WSDualHttpBinding, I am also using security tokens so the protocol is SOAP. I am wondering if there is something I can do when I set up the endpoint? It seems like that might be a good place? I am not sure though.

So, how do I get a list of subscribers such that I can access any of the subscribed clients whenever my service is called? I am guessing there is a good way to do this hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just can say what i have done (i dont know if it is a good style:) but it works).

i create a service with InstanceContextMode.Single

```
 [ServiceBehavior(
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Service : IService
{}
```

i use a simple dictionary to hold my client "connections" in which the key is the client "ID".

```
private static Dictionary<GUID, IAdvServiceCallback> Subscribers;
```

i define a subscribe and unsubscribe methode

```
    public bool Subscribe(GUID key)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Subscribers == null)
            {
                Subscribers = new Dictionary<GUID, IAdvServiceCallback>();
            }

            lock (Subscribers)
            {
                IServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallback>();

                if (!Subscribers.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    Subscribers.Add(key,callback);
                    ICommunicationObject obj = (ICommunicationObject)callback;
                    obj.Closed += SubscribedServiceClosed;
                    obj.Faulted += SubscribedServiceFaulted;
                }
                else
                {
                    //log subscriber is registered
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public bool UnSubscribe()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Subscribers == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            lock (Subscribers)
            {
                IServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallback>();
                if (Subscribers.ContainsValue(callback))
                {
                    var row = Subscribers.Where(v => v.Value == callback).FirstOrDefault();

                    Subscribers.Remove(row.Key);
                }    
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and now the service can send messages to all subscribers

```
Subscribers.Values.ToList().ForEach(delegate(IServiceCallback callback)
            {
                if (((ICommunicationObject) callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                {
                   //send callback
                }
                else
                {
                   // remove subscriber because channel its not open anymore
                }
             });
```

Comment: I finally had time to look at this. Yes, your answer works. I think I will just create a separate service that does nothing but handle subscriptions and calling callbacks that way I don't need to worry about making my services that do the business logic a singleton.